# How to restore the dump into your running mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongorestore, data-dump

I want to load data/restore dump data in mongoDB using mongorestore. I am trying to command

```
mongorestore dump
```

but it giving me error

```
Sat Sep 21 16:12:33.403 JavaScript execution failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

How can we restore or put data into mongoDB?? Please give me the steps.

Comment: God knows why exactly you are getting this error. But make sure you are having `mongod` running in background. Though it has nothing to with this error. By the way did you manually changed the dump files?

Comment: No I downloaded the assignment  dump file. and extracted it.If you have done earlier can you please give me steps.

Comment: Are you doing that mongodb 101 course? I also did that, it worked for me. I hope you have the binaries of `mongorestore` of a stable mongodb release.

Comment: yes, I am doing the same. might me I am going it in wrong way. could you please give me way, where to put dump.bson. my db path is dbpath=C:\mongodb\data\db\

Comment: Actually I use Mac OS X. Really don't know much about Windows. Try following the instructions they give for windows. Or better discuss at their course forum. Many might have faced similar problem. Tension not, ho jayega :)

Comment: Same query exactly what the sh*t i needed . Thanks for asking the query it helps !!

Comment: @SandeepSingh Suggestion - Its always good to accept an answer. People looking for a solution to the same problem can just see that right up as the first answer.

Comment: @Naman - Yes you are correct, certainly I missed to accept the right answer as there was not any answer when I posted it. Now it will very unfair for others, if I am going to accept any answer from this. :)

Comment: @SandeepSingh you can always choose what is the most reasonably explained and useful answer according to you. (despite the votes) ..breaking a tie could also happen using the time when the answer was posted. <= *opinions*

Answer (score 115):

**mongodump:**
To dump all the records:

```
mongodump --db databasename
```

---

To limit the amount of data included in the database dump, you can specify --db and --collection as options to mongodump. For example:

```
mongodump --collection myCollection --db test
```

This operation creates a dump of the collection named myCollection from the database 'test' in a dump/ subdirectory of the current working directory.
NOTE: mongodump overwrites output files if they exist in the backup data folder.

---

**mongorestore:**
To restore all data to the original database:

```
1) mongorestore --verbose \path\dump
```

or restore to a new database:

```
2) mongorestore --db databasename --verbose \path\dump\<dumpfolder>
```

Note: Both requires mongod instances.

Comment: How to pass the DB credentials when restoring?

Comment: @Benjamin `mongorestore -u <username> --authenticationDatabase "admin" --db databasename`. Authentication database not necessarily 'admin', but probably. You should be asked for the password interactively (you may also need to elevate with sudo).

Comment: it should be `--db` or `-d` but not `-db`

Answer (score 58):

Dump DB by **mongodump**

```
mongodump --host <database-host> -d <database-name> --port <database-port> --out directory
```

Restore DB by **mongorestore**

With Index Restore

```
mongorestore --host <database-host> -d <database-name> --port <database-port> foldername
```

Without Index Restore

```
mongorestore --noIndexRestore --host <database-host> -d <database-name> --port <database-port> foldername
```

Import Single Collection from CSV [1st row will be used as Col/Key Name]

```
mongoimport --db <database-name> --port <database-port> --collection <collection-name> --type csv --headerline --file /path/to/myfile.csv
```

Import Single Collection from JSON

```
mongoimport --db <database-name> --port <database-port> --collection <collection-name> --file input.json
```

Answer (score 30):

**To restore a single database:**

1. Backup the `testdb` database

   ```
   $ mongodump --db testdb
   ```
2. Restore the `testdb` database to a new database called `testdb2`

   ```
   $ mongorestore --db testdb2 dump/testdb
   ```

**To restore all databases:**

1. Backup all databases

   ```
   $ mongodump
   ```
2. Restore all databases

   ```
   $ mongorestore dump
   ```

Answer (score 14):

The directory should be named 'dump' and this directory should have a directory which contains the .bson and .json files. This directory should be named as your db name.

eg: if your db name is institution then the second directory name should be institution.

After this step, go the directory enclosing the dump folder in the terminal, and run the command

mongorestore --drop.

Do see to it that mongo is up and running.

This should work fine.

Comment: You should be sure before you use --drop in your command cause it will drop the existing collection in the DB and recreate a new collection with the data from the dump file, technically you will loose all the current data(which is not in dump file) from DB in mongo instance..!!!

Answer (score 9):

Follow this path.

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin
```

Run the  cmd in bin folder and paste the below command

```
mongorestore --db <name-your-database-want-to-restore-as> <path-of-dumped-database>
```

For Example:

```
mongorestore --db testDb D:\Documents\Dump\myDb
```

Answer (score 5):

You can take a dump to your local machine using this command:

```
mongodump -h <host>:<port> -u <username> -p <password> -d ubertower-new -o /path/to/destination/directory
```

You can restore from the local machine to your Mongo DB using this command

```
mongorestore -h <host>:<port> -u <username> -p <password> -d <DBNAME> /path/to/destination/directory/<DBNAME>
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Start mongod
2. Navigate to folder where you have extracted "enron.zip" in OS shell(cmd in case of windows)
3. Then type ">mongorestore -d your_db_name dump/enron"

Answer (score 3):

For mongoDB database restore use this command here

```
mongorestore --db databasename --drop <dump/file/path>
```

Comment: You should be sure before you use --drop in your command cause it will drop the existing collection in the DB and recreate a new collection with the data from the dump file, technically you will loose all the current data(which is not in dump file) from DB in mongo instance..!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can also restore your downloaded Atlas Backup `.wt` WiredTiger files (which unzips or untar as a `restore` folder) to your local MongoDB.

First, make a backup of your `/data/db` path. Call it `/data_20200407/db`. Second, copy paste all the `.wt` files from your Atlas Backup restore folder into your local `/data/db` path. Restart your Ubuntu or MongoDB server. Start your Mongo shell and you should have those restored files there.

Answer (score 1):

If you are okay to drop the existing collections then then following command works fine for me.

- Okay to drop the existing collections

```sh
$ uri_complete="your_complete_uri"
$ restoreFileName="your_restore_filename"
$ mongorestore --uri=$uri_complete -v --gzip --archive=$restoreFileName --drop
```

- Not okay to drop existing collections

```sh
$ uri_complete="your_complete_uri"
$ restoreFileName="your_restore_filename"
$ mongorestore --uri=$uri_complete -v --gzip --archive=$restoreFileName
```

If your database is running on localhost on default port without authentication then the following will work.

```sh
$ mongorestore -v --gzip --archive=restorefile.gzip --drop
```

More details - [mongorestore](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/program/mongorestore/)

Answer (score 0):

I have been through a lot of trouble so I came up with my own solution, I created this script, just set the path inside script and db name and run it, it will do the trick

```
#!/bin/bash

FILES= #absolute or relative path to dump directory
DB=`db` #db name
for file in $FILES
do

    name=$(basename $file)
    collection="${name%.*}"
    echo `mongoimport --db "$DB" --file "$name" --collection "$collection"`

done
```

Answer (score 0):

> mongodump --host test.mongodb.net --port 27017 --db  --username  --password  --authenticationDatabase admin --ssl --out
>
> mongorestore --db  --verbose

Answer (score 0):

Process of Backup MongoDb Collections.

1. Find the MongoDb folder in ProgramFiles or ProgramFiles32.
2. Navigate to **bin** Folder.Find the path like this.**C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin**
3. Make you have to Install Mongo Dump Tools.
   [image]
4. If you are not find any such tools , kindly go through this link and install it. [MongDb Database Tools](https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/database-tools)
5. inside bin Folder open CMD or navigate to MongdDb Server Bin folder.
6. Run this Command **mongodump --db yourdatabasename**. after running this command Dump creation process will start and it will create and one Dump folder in side bin.

**Restore Process**

7. open the CMD prompt in Mongdb Server bin Folder.
8. after that Run this Command **mongorestore --db mydababse --verbose
9. D:\MongoDbBackup\mydababse\Dec28-21**(this this path where I have store my backup collection).
10. some time mongDb Restore program required folder permission to restore.

Answer (score -1):

For mongoDB database restore use this command here .
First go to your mongodb database location such as 
For Example :
**cd Downloads/blank_db/v34000**
After that Enter mongorestore -d v34000 ./