# How to import dump folder into mongodb database?

Tags: mongodb, import, robo3t

I have created a `mongo dump` from a remote server and **.bson** and **.metadata** files stored in to a folder.

I want to `import` this folder into my local `mongodb`. I am using `robomongo` as a `mongodb client ui`.

I got some command which are importing json files one by one but I want `import` all the files at a time by robomongo or cmd.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to restore the dump into your running mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18931668/how-to-restore-the-dump-into-your-running-mongodb)

Comment: mongorestore -d <db_name> <dump_path>

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Try with this:

```
mongorestore -d db_name dump_folder_path
```

Comment: Hint: I tried to run it from mongo console to no avail. It should be run from system shell.

Comment: If you don't have Mongo DB Tools then it will not work on the system shell so install it first then try

Answer (score 7):

`mongodump` is a util for creating a binary export of the database. `mongodump` is used in conjunction with `mongorestore` as a backup strategy.

If you wanted to restore your `mongodump` then you would need to use [mongorestore](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/)

Or,

You could take an export with [mongoexport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/) and then use [mongoimport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/)

Comment: @SangramBadi I’ve  updated my answer with the links. Examples and options are all there too

Answer (score 7):

Go to relevant folder where dump is located by terminal

> mongorestore --host localhost --port 27017 --db [DB_name_in_mongodb] dump/[DB_name_in_dump]

Answer (score 1):

Sharing steps for ubuntu users:

> 1. Open a terminal and go to your Home directory
> 2. Create a folder with name **dump** and add your folder which you want to add.
> 3. Write command `mongorestore` and enter it will restore all your documents.
> 4. Open your `robomongo` and connect with the localhost and refresh.

Your new documents start reflecting now. Enjoy :)

Answer (score 1):

- Install database tools in local computer
- restart your command prompt
- copy C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Tools\100\bin> location and open this in CMD
- run mongorestore --db dbname complete_folder_location
- open mongoDB compass, refresh
- Done