# How to import a mongodump into my local mongodb database using pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongodump, mongorestore

I have a mongodump from a mongodb cloud.Its available locally on my pc.Now I want to create a new mongdb database. And access files locally using queries.I used pymongo for this. Here is my code:

```
    import pymongo
    client = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017')
    database = client['db_name']
    mongorestore -d db_name adress_of_mongodump
    //mongorestore -d database C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\home\ubuntu\dump2020
```

but i'm unable to access the mongodump.Instead getting a syntax error on mongorestore

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48682173/how-to-import-dump-folder-into-mongodb-database

Comment: yeah the solution in the link is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

pymongo does not include a mongorestore capability. If you want to run this from python, you must install the mongorestore to the machine, and execute it with the `subprocess.run()` command; something like:

```
import subprocess

address_of_mongodump = 'c:/address_of_mongodump'
command = ['mongorestore', '--uri', 'mongodb://localhost:27017', f'--archive={address_of_mongodump}']

subprocess.run(command, capture_output=True)
```