# How to restore archive mongoDB database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongorestore

I have to restore the MongoDB archive tar file (when I extract it shows  .wt files inside the tar folder)

```
tar:      restore-63bbdc996664dc2524cce24d.tar

after extract all files like:    collection-0--423807093138670367.wt
```

I tried

- Create a backup of C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\5.0\data
- Place all the .wt files from archive tar in this folder
- Restart the Mongo server with the windows services.

I also tried

```
mongorestore --host localhost --port 27017 --db restoredTest C:\Users\rustam\restore-634235
```

Comment: How was that .tar created?

Comment: Only one single `.wt` file? This would be rather unlikely.

Comment: I have all collections in .wt Extention, I got the tar file by the dump on the live MongoDB server

Comment: when i extract tar file, i got lots of .wt extention file of all collections

Comment: When you take a copy of .wt files, then you must copy the files to new location (not via mongorestore). Hopefully the MongoDB was stopped or at least you run `db.fsyncLock()` while copy was taken. Otherwise the .wt files could be corrupt. Note, there are a few more files - you need to copy all of them.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit, what should I do next after copy all the files

Comment: Simply start the MongoDB

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit, i got the solution, posted the correct answer below

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to restore the dump into your running mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18931668/how-to-restore-the-dump-into-your-running-mongodb)

Comment: Dear @Mandeep, mongodump used for .Bson or .Json files but i have .wt files,
Anyway! I got the solution mention in the answer below.
Thanks for your comments

Answer (score 0):

After spending a lot of time on it finally I got the solution

1. Extract the tar file
2. Run the below command

```bash
mongod --port your_port --dbpath your_extracted_tar_folder
```

note: port is optional, it will run 27027 default port

3. Go and connect on the same port that you pass