# How to restore dump backup in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodump, mongorestore

I have restore-63bbdc996664dc2524cce24d.tar file, I am restoring it in the MongoDB database

tried these commands

mongodump --db test --gzip --archive=restore-63bbdc996664dc2524cce24d.tar

mongodump --db test --archive=restore-63bbdc996664dc2524cce24d.tar

mongodump --host localhost --port 27017 --db test --gzip --archive=restore-63bbdc996664dc2524cce24d.tar

mongorestore --drop C:\Users\rustam\restore-63bbdc996664dc2524cce24d.tar.gz -v

**error** => Failed: file C:\Users\rustam\restore-63bbdc996664dc2524cce24d.tar.gz does not have
.bson extension

I also tried to convert this file to bson by the command

bsondump --outFile=C:\Users\rustam\restore-63bbdc996664dc2524cce24d.tar.gz coll.bson

Can anyone please tell me what should I do to restore the database?

Thanks in advance for any comment or answer.

Comment: try the `--archive=<file>` option: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongorestore/#std-option-mongorestore.--archive

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to restore archive mongoDB database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75057872/how-to-restore-archive-mongodb-database)

Comment: @godo57, I also tried --archive=<file>but not getting restore yet

Comment: How did you get your .tar dump ?

Comment: I am getting database backup by the atlas server every day, it returns me .tar file

Comment: According to mongodb documentation : https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongorestore/#synopsis, The `mongorestore` program loads data from either a binary database dump created by `mongodump`

Comment: I don't have .bson extension files, do you know how to convert it into .bson extention?

Comment: I don't know what kind of files you have

Answer (score 0):

1. Extract the archive file using `tar -xvf restore-63bbdc996664dc2524cce24d.tar`
2. Use `mongorestore --db test --drop <path/to/extracted/bson/files>` to restore the dump.

Keep in mind that this command will drop any existing collections in that database before restoring, so make sure you have taken necessary backups.

Comment: yes! I tried this but I don't have Bson files after extract,

Answer (score 0):

After spending a lot of time on it finally I got the solution

```
1. Extract the tar file
2. Run the below command

mongod --port your_port --dbpath your_extracted_tar_folder

note: port is optional, it will run 27027 default port 
3. Go and connect on the same port that you pass
```