# How to restore MongoDB with .wt files

Tags: mongodb

I'm currently trying to restore Mongo backup files from Atlas, which contains .wt collection and index files. But I'm not sure how to. Atlas compressed the snapshot into a .tar.gz file so I extracted it and attempted to use mongorestore with it. However, after using mongorestore, all of the files in the restore folder are coming back with an error "don't know what to do with file (file path), skipping...".

Does anyone know what I should do? I'm not very experienced, so I would greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: Hope this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18931668/how-to-restore-the-dump-into-your-running-mongodb

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this might have been posted here as well which has the answer - https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/accessing-data-from-atlas-snapshot-wt-files/232259